# Обособление приложения одновременно с помощью тире и запятой

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, приложение

Возможна ли вместо второго тире запятая, если нет дополнительных условий, при которых погашается второе тире?

**Она пригласила двух сестёр – Катю и Лену, и начала готовить ужин.**

И можно ли совсем не использовать второе тире в таком случае:

**Однажды отец взял троих своих сыновей – Мишу, Диму и Ваню и повёз их на рыбалку.** 
P.S. согласно правилу, если приложение выражает более конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово – более общее значение, то второе тире опускается http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.h  На совещании **министров иностранных дел – членов «большой восьмёрки»** выступил министр иностранных дел России.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Правильно: Она пригласила двух сестёр, **Катю и Лену**, и начала готовить ужин.

Тире для обособления двух приложений, связанных союзом И (Катю и Лену) обычно не используется. (Ряд в этом случае обособляется как одна фраза, одно слово).

Кроме того, при обособлении приложений с помощью тире второе тире о**пускается перед запятой, но не перед союзом И.**

2) Пояснение

Розенталь:http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:
1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится **запятая:** Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки; Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров;

Но: Достали глубиномер — г**ирьку на длинной бечёвке** — и промерили глубину;

Однажды отец взял троих своих сыновей – **Мишу, Диму и Ваню** – и повёз их на рыбалку.

3) На совещании (министров иностранных дел – членов «большой восьмёрки») //выступил министр иностранных дел России.

Это особый случай, в этом примере мы имеем так называемое тире-дефис, так как всё сочетание произносится **без паузы,** в одну фразу.

Comment: *министров иностранных дел – членов «большой восьмёрки»* — здесь пропущено слово **стран**?

Comment: Последний пример рассмотрен по приведенной Вами ссылке. Никакого "тире-дефис" там нет — обычное тире.

Comment: Графически это обычное тире, оно необычно с точи зрения интонации.  Тире-дефис - это не общепринятый термин, это домашний термин для себя, который встречался мне в некоторых учебных пособиях. Но так как Розенталь его не употребляет, то лучше про него "на людях" не говорить.  Итак, почему тире-дефис? Это тире ставится, если определяемое слово и приложение распространены, но читается всё сочетание в одну фразу (без обозначение паузы, характерной для тире), как читалось бы нераспространенное сочетание  "стран-членов" (обычно прочтение без паузы всех дефисных написаний).