# Что такое "тире-дефис" и случаи его употребления

Tags: пунктуация, тире, дефис-тире

В ответе на вопрос [Обособление приложения одновременно с помощью тире и запятой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435560/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9/435561#435561) было упомянуто так называемое тире-дефис: "*3) На совещании (министров иностранных дел – членов «большой восьмёрки») //выступил министр иностранных дел России.
Это особый случай, в этом примере мы имеем так называемое **тире-дефис**, так как всё сочетание произносится без паузы, в одну фразу*".

- Хотелось бы подробнее узнать, что это за знак, где про него можно почитать? Это термин из специальной лингвистической литературы, употребляемый в узком научном круге, или им пользуются в более широкой сфере: редакторы, корректоры, учителя, педагоги?

Answer (score 1):

> Хотелось бы подробнее узнать, что это за знак, где про него можно
>   почитать?

Больше всего напоминает личное словообразовательное творчество автора. 
**Тут, видимо, речь о правиле замены дефиса на тире в случае, когда обычно присоединяемое дефисом приложение состоит более чем из одного слова.** В этом случае дефис заменяется на тире, частично это подтверждается и авторским примером - при всей его неудачности. Возможно, есть еще случае замены тире на дефис на тех же основаниях (многословное присоединение), но это уже совсем редкость. Другой интерпретации такому термину я придумать не могу.

Верить же изобретателю этого "термина" не очень хочется, ибо сам пример, как уже заметили, поражает неграмотностью. "Члены стран" - это какой-то сюрреализм с порнографическим уклоном.

Есть, правда, еще некоторые мысли, что автор неверно понял *типографские* термины, которые предписывают различать знаки дефиса, минуса и три вида тире: короткое, длинное и среднее. Но это именно *типографские* правила, к правилам собственно орфографии (и пунктуации) русского языка они отношения не имеют.

Answer (score 0):

На русском языке нигде не встречал такого названия, а в английских описаниях встречается так называемый "*Hyphen-minus*" – в переводе получается композиция дефиса с минусом.

Еще как вариант, "тире-дефис" может быть последствием тяги к русификации всего, что удается русифицировать: в английском существуют "*n dash*" и "*m dash*", различающиеся длиной (первое в два раза короче). Первое ставится, как правило, при обозначении интервала (например, стр. 1–7).

В Вашем примере, если я верно понимаю, в скобках находится достаточно типичное **приложение**, и тире ставится по стандартным правилам. И никакое "тире-дефис" здесь не должно возникать. Приложение не обязано сильно выделяться интонацией.

Comment: **Министры — члены "большой восьмёрки"** — так нельзя сказать. Поэтому вторая часть выражения не может быть приложением. Или предложение составлено неграмотно, или пропущено слово **стран**.

Comment: Пожалуйста, определите вид грамматической конструкции и дайте ссылку на правило, в соответствии с которым  в данном случае ставится одно, а не да тире (желательно использовать известные источники).   Что означает "сильно выделяться интонацией",  это неточное выражение, определите каким-нибудь образом характер интонации.

Comment: И еще: "И никакое "тире-дефис" здесь не должно возникать". Вы уверены, что здесь не следует использовать Р.п. в связи с отрицанием?

Comment: @СтаниславТерляков я подозреваю, что вы на верном пути, полагая авторскую путаницу в терминах. Но объяснения через английский сами по себе не работают. В русском и без английского хватает путаницы с типографскими терминами для знаков "тире", "минус", "перенос" и дефис. Поэтому ваш ответ страдает неполнотой.