# "Рыба тонкая (-) игла". Сохраняется ли дефис?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, приложение, члены-предложения, дефис-тире

Сохраняется ли дефис при приложении, если оно отрывается от определяемого слова? (Текст поэтический, поэтому такой порядок слов.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Рыба — тонкая игла**. Дефис "превратился" в тире.

> [§ 154. В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp154.php).
>   1. В сочетаниях с приложением, если одна из частей содержит пробел.
>   Примеры с неоднословными определяемыми: встреча с гостями Олимпиады — иностранцами, старшего лейтенанта — артиллериста, участников войны — инвалидов, о Михаиле Булгакове — - актёре, у научного сотрудника — космонавта. Ср. гости-иностранцы, лейтенант-артиллерист, воины-инвалиды, Булгаков-актёр, лётчик-космонавт.
>   Примеры с неоднословными приложениями: **творчество поэтов — современников Пушкина; статьи о Горьком — общественном деятеле, о Маршаке — переводчике Шекспира; печальная судьба дома — памятника архитектуры; обратиться к директору — художественному руководителю; среди стран — участников переговоров. Ср. поэты-современники, Горький-писатель, Маршак-переводчик, дом-памятник, директор-распорядитель.**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если это не шутка. Откуда такое правило?

Comment: Не шутка. Ищу для Вас авторитетную ссылку. Пока могу сослаться на @behemothus: "Pечь о правиле замены дефиса на тире в случае, когда обычно присоединяемое дефисом приложение состоит более чем из одного слова" (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437485/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?rq=1)

Comment: Ясно. Но, как я понимаю, здесь приложение является одним словом "игла": рыба-игла. "Тонкая" -- это определение к "рыба-игла"

Comment: Но Вы же не хотите писать "тонкая рыба-игла", а пишете нечто нестандартное, поэтому приходится считать, что приложение "игла" стало состоять из двух слов (тонкая игла), подобно тому как у Лопатина  дом-памятник => дом — памятник архитектуры.

Comment: Может, тогда тире надо поставить так: рыба тонкая -- игла (по примеру:  гости Олимпиады — иностранцы)?

Comment: Можно, по-моему. Автор должен решить, что ему милее: "рыба, тонкая как игла" или "тонкая рыба, похожая на иглу".

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

**Рыба тонкая — игла.**

Исходный вариант — это рыба-игла, морская рыба семейства игловых. Рыба — приложение, которое в данном случае пишется через дефис (сравнить: рыба окунь).

Приложение в поэтическом тексте распространяем и получаем: ***рыба тонкая — игла.*** Дефис заменяется тире.

Обоснование http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Одно тире пишется:

2) если приложение выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или **образное значение**: Прилетели сюда **первые ласточки — наши спортсмены** для участия в парусных гонках;

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется, от контекста зависит...

Например:

"Рыба — тонкая игла
на придонье замерла"

или

"Рыба тонкая — игла,
вязь на глади соткала"